# Statistics: Combination problem

Tags: statistics

Good day everyone.

I'm doing a combination problem and its solution keeps eluding me.

**Problem:**

Of a hand of 13 in a deck of 52 how many combinations are there of none of the cards being greater than 10, assuming that ace is greater than 10.

**Attempted solution:**

There are sixteen cards greater than 10: ace, jack, queen and king (all houses). So of thirteen cards in a house four are too great.

\begin{equation}
\left( \begin{array}{c} 13 \\ 4 \end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

Possible combinations of a hand consisting of only higher than 10 cards is:

\begin{equation}
\left( \begin{array}{c} 16 \\ 13 \end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

Multiply them together and subtract that from

\begin{equation}
\left( \begin{array}{c} 52 \\ 13 \end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

to get the wrong answer. There is something missing or wrong or both and I would appreciate help.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Note that you can produce binomial coefficients more easily using e.g. `\binom nk` to produce $\binom nk$. Also, general matrices in parentheses are more easily produced using e.g. `\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}` rather than `\left(\begin{array}{c}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)` to produce $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to get into the substraction here. You can count directly the "good" hands. You've already shown there are $16$ "bad" cards. That leaves $52-16=36$ good cards. You need to pick $13$ of them. You thus get
$$
\binom {36}{13}
$$
"good" hands